# TimeQuest Timing Analyzer: What is the difference between post fit and post map timing netlists?

Tags: quartus-ii, timing-analysis

When we wish to add timing constraints to our design in TimeQuest Timing Analyzer, we have two options. We can use either a post fit netlist or post map netlist. Post map netlist is available after mere design synthesis, however the post fit netlist is only available after fitting.

Now my question is which is used when?

Is it true that post fit netlist has timing information but post map does not? Besides that, when comiling an FPGA design, is post map netlist defined using the "atoms" of the FPGA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process of mapping implements the specified behavior in the selected technology, but does not assign specific physical resources to the individual elements (e.g., LUTs and FFs). Simulation at this level models the gate delays fairly accurately, but uses statistical averages for the wiring delays.

The process of fitting allocates the specific physical resources for each design element identified during the mapping stage, and also allocates the routing resources required to make the connections. Simulation at this level gets both accurate gate delays as well as wiring delays.

Since fitting is a fairly compute-intensive process, and since post-map simulation is about 90% of the way there in terms of overall timing accuracy, many designers do the bulk of their timing verification using post-map timing.

Comment: What does the term selected technology refer to here?

Comment: Whatever your target technology is. Most FPGAs have LUTs (lookup tables) and FFs (flip-flops), along with more specialized functions such as clock generators, multipliers and block RAMs. Some FPGAs substitute muxes for the LUTs. ASICs (application-specific integrated circuits) will most likely use a predefined library of "standard cells" for specific gate and FF configurations. It is the job of synthesis to map (implement) the specified functionality using the available primitive functions.

Comment: Lets call the Logic blocks, DSP blocks, memory blocks on FPGAs as FPGA resources, what I understand is that after synthesis in say Quartus II, our VHDL has been mapped to these FPGA resources. However, they have not been mapped to specific resources located at XY coordinates on the FPGA. This is done by fitter. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Dear Dave, I wish to send a private message to you but there does not seem to be an apparent way. I have tried sending an email to the address given in your CV but that has returned with a failure message. Basically as I am new in this field and you are quite a senior engineer, I was wondering if you could give me some advice on a few general things in engineering career.